# C# Regex "+" group returning empty string

Tags: c#, regex

I'm trying to match the following strings and extract the numbers:

```
"Control 1"
"Control 2"
```

and I want to make sure that I avoid similar strings such as:

```
"Indication 1"
"Local Control Input 2"
```

This is the pattern I'm using:

```
@"^Control (?<slot>\d+)$"
```

It works perfectly, and `match.Groups["slot"].Value` returns the number. However, I discovered that I also need to be able to match the following:

```
"Office In 1"
"Office In 2"
```

I modified my regex to this:

```
@"^(?:Control)|(?:Office In) (?<slot>\d+)$"
```

The problem is that now, `match.Groups["slot"].Value` is returning an empty string! **Doesn't the `+` require that there be at least one digit?** I randomly tried adding an extra non-capturing group around the two existing ones:

```
@"^(?:(?:Control)|(?:Office In)) (?<slot>\d+)$"
```

That fixes the problem, but I'm not sure why.

Comment: well you're using a noncapturing group, so that definintely makes sense of your results

Comment: @Jonesy I'm using a noncapturing group for the stuff want to check but not capture. I'm capturing the group named "slot".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Alternation has the highest precedence in Regular expressions.  Your original regex is `"^(?:Control)"` (Control at the beginning of the string) OR `"(?:Office In) (?<slot>\d+)$"` (Office In #### at the end of the string).

Try this regular expression:

```
@"^(?:Control|Office In) (?<slot>\d+)$"
```